# Modifying the dictionary value in python ( getting strange results)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
for index,line in enumerate(status):
   for word in line:
      if word not in score_dict:
        non_sentiment_dictionary[word].extend([original_sentiment[index]])
```

The above is my code..  Some background information..  status is nested lists.  it has several sentences and I already split the words in each sentence so that each sentence itself is a list.

For example, status=[['I','Love','You' ],['You ','are','awesome']]

score_dict and non_sentiment_dictionary are dictionary. for example 
score_dict = {'love': 5, 'awesome': 3}

the original dictionary values of non_sentiment_dictionary are empty.

and, there is original_sentiment list, which is just simple integer array. To make things simple, 
let's say it is list full of zeros.

what I want to do is for each word in each line of status, if that word is not included in score_dict, then, modify the dictionary value with that word key. in this case, extend the list.

for example, if the word 'are' is not in score_dict, then, we extend the list non_sentiment_dictionary['are'].

The problem is that for some reasons that  I don't understand non_sentiment_dictionary grows very fast because every time the list is extended, it seems to get the whole value of the previous loop.

Here is the results after I put some print statements to understand what is going on.

Let's say 'sky' is already [0,0,0,0 ]. When we see the word 'god' for the first time in the loop, 
we should only get [0].

But, I got the following [0,0,0,0]. It seems to copy value of dictionary that I have previously accessed even though the original dictionary values of non_sentiment_dictionary are empty.

```
sky
[0, 0, 0, 0]
god
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Extend takes a list and appends another list to it - you want to append a value to a simple list that may not yet exist:

```
non_sentiment_dictionary.setdefault(word, []).append([original_sentiment[index]])
```